# I don't understand how private constructor can't create instances outside and prevents subclassing (while he doing all that!)

Tags: java, constructor, private

It's known that private constructor prevents creating instances outside the class. Also they say it prevents sublcassing because it doesn't allow to call super. But... it seems like it i can create multiple instances and can call **super** (or what is wrong?):

```
public class TestPrivate {

    private static int i;

    class A {
        private String s = "Constructor ";
        private A() {
            print();
        }
        void print() { 
            s += getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + ++i;
            System.out.println(s); }
    }

    class B extends A {

        B() {
            super(); // <--- i can call super 
            super.print();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestPrivate test = new TestPrivate();
        // creating multiple objects with private constructors
        test.new A();
        test.new A(); // <--- i can call constructor outsised the class many times

        test.new B();
    }
}
```

Output:
Constructor A 1
Constructor A 2
Constructor B 3
Constructor B 3B 4

Comment: Create distinct file for class `A` and `B`, the private doesn't prevent access for inner class like this

Comment: Classes inside the same outer class can access private members.  It is assumed that if you do this, you know what you are doing and that your left hand is not trying to stop your right hand from coding for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private` access means , you can access within the whole `Class`. Since **Class B** is inside the **Class A**, Class B will be treated as a member of Class and can freely access the constructor of `A`

If you have a [look at docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), it is clearly mentioned.

> A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, **even if they are declared private.**

Comment: I was looking the information in the **Controlling Access to Members of a Class** page. This explain why I couldn't find anything proving my point.

Answer (score 2):

You are using inner classes. This means that `A` and `B` are both members of `TestPrivate`.

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) says (when the member or constructor is declared `private`):

> access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

So, any access to private members and private constructors of any members is allowed *within the body of `TestPrivate`*.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing  `test.new A();` in a main method inside of the same class/file (TestPrivate class), no reason why you just can not access all the methods, including the private ones....